# Spam written by registred users

Tags: posts, spam

I have build a small wordpress site with two users with role=author. Recently spam posts are made from those two of the users - they are infrequent (one pr month of so), short, without any links and with random subjects like:

"Is It Possible To Speed Read Like These Famous Pace Visitors",
"Welcome world"
and
"Infact, a decade previously classic writers used the tips to advertising and circulating publications."

I have reset their passwords and seems it has helped although I cannot be sure due to the infrequent posts made.

Now I wonder how is this possible and what to do about it.

Comment: they can make a procedure of password reset and then re-acces to the backend. to block them of publishing new posts, change the roles from "author" to "contributor" or another role for which the personn don't have the capability of publishing.

Comment: Exactly what is your question? How it's possible that a user submits random subjects, or how a user's account might get compromised by a third partyß

Comment: The question is: how is it possible that two user accounts can be compromised